# Cannot install Devise in Rails 5.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm running Rails 5.0.2 on a Cloud9 install. I successfully `bundle install` Devise 4.2.1, but when I try `rails g devise:install` I get an error.

Here's my command line after bundle updating:

```
$ bundle update
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.8.1
Using minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 2.0.1
Using nio4r 2.0.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 7.1.4 (was 8.0.0)
Using public_suffix 2.0.5
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using bundler 1.14.6
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using thor 0.19.4
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0 (was 0.0.7)
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.8
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using pg 0.20.0
Using puma 3.8.2
Using rubyzip 1.2.1
Using sass 3.4.23
Using tilt 2.0.7
Using websocket 1.2.4
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.3
Using nokogiri 1.7.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.7
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using mime-types 3.1
Using addressable 2.5.1
Using childprocess 0.6.3
Using rb-inotify 0.9.8
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using activesupport 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using xpath 2.0.0
Using mail 2.6.5
Using selenium-webdriver 3.4.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.2
Using globalid 0.4.0
Using activemodel 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using jbuilder 2.6.3
Using spring 2.0.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using capybara 2.13.0
Using activejob 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using activerecord 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using actionview 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using actionpack 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using actioncable 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using actionmailer 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using railties 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.2.1
Using responders 2.3.0
Using web-console 3.5.0
Using rails 5.0.2 (was 5.1.0)
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Using devise 4.2.1 (was 1.5.4)
Bundle updated!
```

All looks good. Now let's try installing devise.

```
$ rails g devise:install
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000414dfd0> (NoMethodError)
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/eps-donation-pages/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/eps-donation-pages/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:EpsDonationPages>'
            from /home/ubuntu/workspace/eps-donation-pages/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
            from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I originally tried Rails 5.1.0, but apparently Devise doesn't support this yet (Unless I'm mistaken)

Comment: try removing the version info from devise: like gem 'devise' and bundle install and then try re installing devise with the reails g devise:install command

Comment: For whatever reason this was defaulting devise to version 1.5.x

EDIT: Looks like this was due to using Rails 5.1.0 (which was released just yesterday, April 27th) then attempting to downgrade to 5.0.2. Creating a new application with 5.0.2 from the outset and adding `gem 'devise'` installed the latest version of Devise and solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue was due to using Rails 5.1.0 (which was released just yesterday, April 27th) then attempting to downgrade to 5.0.2. Creating a new application with 5.0.2 from the outset and adding gem 'devise' installed the latest version of Devise and solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Gemfile, please include devise like this for now:

```
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', ref: '83002017'
```